# Getting tmux to copy a buffer to the clipboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, clipboard, xclip

I am trying to figure out a decent way to copy what I have in a tmux buffer into my clipboard.  I have tried a couple of different things like

```
bind-key p select-pane -t 2 \; split-window 'xsel -i -b' \; paste-buffer
```

which gets me fairly close, all I have to do is hit control-d after I do prefix-p.

I tried fixing that by doing

```
bind-key p select-pane -t 2 \; split-window 'xsel -i -b << HERE\; tmux paste-buffer\; echo HERE'
```

But that just doesn't work.  In fact if I pair this down to just

```
bind-key p select-pane -t 2 \; split-window 'xsel -i -b << HERE'
```

it doesn't do anything so I am assuming that split-window doesn't like << in a shell command.

Any ideas?

Edit:
You can skip the `select-pane -t 2` if you want, it isn't really important.  I just use a specific layout and pane 2 is the one I prefer to split when I doing something else so that goes into my bindings involving splits by default.

Comment: Make sure to look at the below 2014 answer, which is more recent than some of the other ones. It recommends the tmux yank plugin which works very well.

Comment: For an answer that is up-to-date with Tmux 2.4 (released April 2017) and 2.6 see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409972/14252)

Comment: Tmux 3.0a Ubuntu 20.04 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607112/148062

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here documents need newlines. For example, in a shell script, you can write

```
cat <<EOF >somefile; echo  done
file contents
EOF
```

I don't think tmux lets you put newlines there, and even if it did, this wouldn't be a good approach. What if the data itself contains `HERE` alone on a line (e.g. because you're copying your `.tmux.conf`)?

I suggest to write the buffer contents to a temporary file. Untested:

```
bind-key p save-buffer ~/.tmux-buffer \; run-shell "xsel -i -b <~/.tmux-buffer && rm ~/.tmux-buffer"
```

There's a race condition if you use this command in two separate tmux instances. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly, the race condition isn't a concern for me, I only use 1 session.

Comment: To avoid race condition, I'd suggest using `mktemp` which is widely available

Comment: @Grief Good idea. In this case, using the PID of the tmux process would work as well and would probably be easier to arrange (`$PPID` in a shell launched by tmux). But how do you get the variable file name (however it's constructed) into the argument of `save-buffer`? I guess `save-buffer - | …` like in [Grauwolf's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16405), which does away with a temporary file altogether?

Comment: You are correct, my fault, this would not be possible.

Answer (score 97):

This should work:

```
# move x clipboard into tmux paste buffer
bind C-p run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
# move tmux copy buffer into x clipboard
bind C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i"
```

Comment: So it does. That's much nicer than using a temporary file, thanks. It even automatically copes with multiple concurrent sessions, thanks to the `TMUX` environment variables.

Comment: A better instruction for the `C-p` would be: `bind C-p run "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"` -- no quoting issues or command line limit issues.

Comment: # move x clipboard into tmux paste buffer
bind C-p run "tmux set-buffer \\"$(xclip -o)\\"; tmux paste-buffer"
# # move tmux copy buffer into x clipboard
bind C-y run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -i -selection clipboard,primary"

Comment: Does tmux have a hook to copy the selection into the clipboard when in `copy-mode`?

Comment: `xclip -o` option didn't worked for me so I've changed to `bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -selection c"\; display-message "Buffer copied to clipboard"`

Comment: Every time I do the copy this way, tmux stops responding to any keyboard shortcuts. Any solution to that?

Comment: excellent solution. to further simplify it [saveb](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) command shortcut (alias) might be used. there's also `-a` switch to append instead of overwrite (the file or output).

Comment: @skrat Tmux waits for xclip to close stdout which takes a long time. To fix it change `xclip -i` to `xclip -i > /dev/null`. See my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409972/14252) for more details.

Comment: For those using the emacs key bindings you want to use this `bind-key -Tcopy-mode  M-w run "tmux copy-pipe-and-cancel \"xclip\""`

Comment: I am using this in conjunction with MobaXterm and Windows and it works like a treat.  Important to mention that MobaXterm has a built-in X Server to be able to receive and send the clip buffer.

Answer (score 45):

The `copy-pipe` command was added as of version 1.8. It copies a selection to the tmux buffer and pipes it to a command. Now there is no need for a prefix binding. Here's an example:

```
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip"

# For OS X users:
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

Now when you have some text selected in `copy-mode`, <kbd>y</kbd> will copy that text to the tmux buffer as well as the OS clipboard. However, it doesn't help if you want to get text from the clipboard to the tmux buffer.

Comment: Works perfectly and is the simplest solution of the bunch.

Comment: Doesn't work for me under Linux, this one does though: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131074/13601

Comment: As of OS X 10.10, it appears `reattach-to-user-namespace` is not necessary.

Comment: works on el capitan

Comment: This no longer works for Tmux 2.4 which was released on April 20, 2017. Instead you need to use `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip"` and for OS X: `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"`

Comment: As of Tmux 2.4 (April, 2017) this answer is outdated. Instead you need to use `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip"` or `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"` for Mac. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409972/14252) for more details.

Comment: It still does not work...

Answer (score 43):

#### A simpler solution for Mac OS-X

This builds off of Alex's answer and uses stuff that didn't exist at the time.

If you are using [homebrew](https://brew.sh) (and if you aren't, why aren't you?) then you can just do this:

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Then in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh" # or bash...
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind C-v run "reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer"
```

To copy the *buffer* from tmux (you should have already copied something using tmux) into the Mac pasteboard, use `<tmux-key> Control-c`.  It will now be available for `Command-v` or `pbpaste`

To paste something from the Mac pasteboard, use `<tmux-key> Control-v`.

Comment: This answer is superb.  I was using `tmux show-buffer` which caused line wrap issues `tmux save-buffer -` solved it.

Comment: What does the `-` at the end of `tmux save-buffer -` do?

Comment: Emits the `save-buffer` to stdout.  You can replace the `-` with a filename and it'll save it there.  This prevents you from writing (and having to clean up) a file.

Comment: As of OS X 10.10 reattach-to-user-namespace is no longer necessary. Almost every tutorial and documentation regarding tmux and OS X mentions it, because copy & pasting wasn’t easily possible a couple of years ago. These days it (mostly) works out of the box.

Answer (score 17):

You might want to try [tmux-yank plugin](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank). It enables copying straight to system clipboard (OS X and Linux) and some other goodies like yanking the current shell line.

Comment: This is a great, clean solution and should be considered more since it's a much more recent answer than the others. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 16):

Here is an attempt at a comprehensive answer.

### First a little history

When this question was first asked (June, 2011) copying text from Tmux to the clipboard had to be a two-step process, first copy the selected text to Tmux's buffer, then copy the text from Tmux's buffer to the system clipboard.

In 1.8 (March, 2013) the `copy-pipe` command was added which allows you to copy the selected text straight into the system clipboard (or other destination).

Then in 2.4 (April, 2017) the key tables were significantly changed rendering many of the answers on this page obsolete.

### Answering the original question

**Linux**:

```
bind-key C-y run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -r > /dev/null" \; display-message "Copied tmux buffer to selection"
bind-key C-Y run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -r -selection clipboard > /dev/null" \; display-message "Copied tmux buffer to clipboard"
bind-key C-p run-shell "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

**Mac**:

If you are using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then you should install `reattach-to-user-namespace` by running the following command in a terminal:

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Then in your ~/.tmux.conf:

```
bind-key C-y run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy" \; display-message "Copied tmux buffer to clipboard"
bind-key C-p run-shell "reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

### The Shorter Method (copy and paste a selection straight from and to the clipboard for tmux>2.4)

Note: there are two versions for Linux because Linux has a primary and secondary clipboard (also known as selection).

**Linux**:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip -r" \; display-message "Copied to selection"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Y send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip -r -selection clipboard" \; display-message "Copied to clipboard"
bind-key C-p run-shell "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer"
```

**Mac**:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy" \; display-message "Copied to clipboard"
```

### Customizing these commands

- If you don't want the command to tell you what it did in the status line then just remove the `display-message` (as well as the `\;` that comes before it).
- If you are using the Emacs style copy-mode instead of vi then replace any instance of `copy-mode-vi` with just `copy-mode`
- If you are running Linux and you want to use `xsel` instead of `xclip` replace `xclip -r` with `xsel -i -p` and `xclip -o` with `xsel -o -p`
- The `-r` in `xclip -r` is optional, it removes the last newline. It is useful for copying commands, then when you paste them they won't be immediately executed.
- If you are tunneling over SSH then you should consult https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354581/14252

**References:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21190234/175830

  - Without `> /dev/null` copying the tmux buffer to the clipboard will cause tmux to not respond to shortcuts
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70798/14252

  - Mac customizations

Comment: Is this command `bind-key C-p run-shell "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"`, still valid? for `tmux>2.4`

Comment: Maybe I'm too new to to tmux but I didn't understand how to use it on linux:
I've added this:


<bind-key C-y run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -r > /dev/null" \; display-message "Copied tmux buffer to selection">


And after seeing I've copied data to my buffer, I'm trying to press C-P for pasting which doesn't paste the stuff I have in the buffer... help?

Answer (score 9):

After trying different solution, here is my final setup:

```
# move x clipboard into tmux paste buffer
bind C-p run "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer -
# move tmux copy buffer into x clipboard
bind C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

using save-buffer instead of show-buffer gives the real data without the data as shown with line-breaks when you are in splits.

I also use this to begin selection/copy in tmux copy-mode:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

I guess it could be possible to merge the copy-selection with the 'y' key AND move it to the x clipboard.

Comment: I was trying to merge both commands as you mentioned with no success. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

I dislike having extra key presses, so I wanted something more ambitious.  Enter copy mode with [, highlight the right text, and then press ] to copy the text to the clipboard.

Also, tmux likes to include newlines in expressions that wrap (and oddly those newlines are in the *wrong* place!  They aren't where the expression wrapped on the screen).  So I wanted C-] to copy the expression removing the newlines.

On tmux 1.6 I tried this:

```
bind [ copy-mode
bind -t vi-copy ] run "tmux send-keys Enter; tmux show-buffer | xclip -i -selection clipboard;"
bind -t vi-copy C-] run "tmux send-keys Enter; tmux show-buffer | perl -pe 's/\n//' | xclip -i -selection clipboard;"
```

but that didn't work because tmux doesn't seem happy to bind complex things to the vi-copy table.  So I ended up doing this instead:

```
bind [ copy-mode \;                                                        \
    bind -n ] run                                                          \
    "tmux send-keys Enter;                                                 \
     tmux show-buffer | xclip -i -selection clipboard;                     \
     tmux unbind -n C-];                                                   \
     tmux unbind -n ]" \;                                                  \
    bind -n C-] run                                                        \
    "tmux send-keys Enter;                                                 \
     tmux show-buffer | perl -pe 's/\n//' | xclip -i -selection clipboard; \
     tmux unbind -n C-];                                                   \
     tmux unbind -n ]"
```

This leads to weird things (] or C-] will act funny the next time you use them, but only once) if you exit from copy mode in another way besides ] or C-].  This could be fixed with some more bindings I imagine, but this does what I want most of the time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10954274/69663 notes that there's a related bug report on the limitations of bind-key at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3533562&group_id=200378&atid=973262

Answer (score 5):

A solution for Mac OS X.  Follow these 2 steps:

1. Use Chris Johnsen's workaround:  https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard
2. Add this code to your tmux config (~/.tmux.conf)

```
# paste clipboard into tmux buffer
bind v run-shell "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh -c 'tmux set-buffer \\"$(pbpaste)\\"; tmux paste-buffer'"
# put tmux buffer into x clipboard
bind y run-shell "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh -c 'tmux show-buffer | pbcopy'"
```

Answer (score 5):

A slightly modified variant of the accepted answer, which I cooked up.

I also prefer to use the system clipboard (Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V) in addition to xclip's `primary` default clipboard (the one you get with mouse selection and mouse middle-clicks). For choosing the system clipboard you need to pass `-selection clipboard` argument to `xclip`.

Also while copying a buffer into a clipboard, I like the ability to choose which buffer I want to copy. It is done using `choose-buffer` and then passing buffer the argument to `save-buffer` using `-b %%`.

```
# Copy into clipboard
bind C-c choose-buffer "run \"tmux save-buffer -b %% - | xclip -i -selection clipboard\""
# Paste from clipboard
bind C-v run "xclip -o -selection clipboard | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
# Copy into primary
bind C-y choose-buffer "run \"tmux save-buffer -b %% - | xclip -i \""
# Paste from primary
bind C-p run "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

**UPDATE:**
Somehow with tmux 1.8 and two of my openSUSE 12.2 installations, I see a hang when `tmux run-shell` is invoked with `xclip` reading from stdin over a pipe. I instead decided to give `xsel` a try and that seems to work. These are the equivalent key bindings using `xsel`. I also used `&&` to chain the commands in paste for more robustness.

```
# Copy into clipboard
bind C-c choose-buffer "run \"tmux save-buffer -b '%%' - | xsel -i -b\""
# Paste from clipboard
bind C-v run "xsel -o -b | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer"
# Copy into primary
bind C-y choose-buffer "run \"tmux save-buffer -b '%%' - | xsel -i\""
# Paste from primary
bind C-p run "xsel -o | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my rather lengthy answer that should fix two major problems with using xclip to copy the buffer from a remote (ssh) tmux session:

## 1. Irresponsive xclip

For me @Grauwolf's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16405/152329) with `xclip` didn't work (renders tmux pane totally irresponsive).
I found out why in the [Tmux page of the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#X_clipboard_integration):

> xclip could also be used for that purpose, unlike xsel it works better on printing raw bitstream that doesn't fit the current locale. Nevertheless, it is neater to use xsel instead of xclip, because xclip does not close STDOUT after it has read from tmux's buffer. As such, tmux doesn't know that the copy task has completed, and continues to wait for xclip's termination, thereby rendering tmux unresponsive. A workaround is to **redirect STDOUT of xclip to /dev/null**

So the binding should be:

```
bind-key C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clip > /dev/null"
```

Now, this will work if your tmux session is local.

## 2. xclip unable to connect to X

**If you are using tmux over ssh -X**, there are big chances this **won't work** directly.

That's because the shell variable `$DISPLAY` needs to be set properly.

## Complete solution

So for me, **the complete working solution** is to put the following lines in my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g update-environment "DISPLAY"
bind-key C-y run "export DISPLAY=`tmux show-env | sed -n 's/^DISPLAY=//p'`; tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard >/dev/null"
# Or more concise:
bind-key C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard -d `tmux show-env | sed -n 's/^DISPLAY=//p'` >/dev/null
```

For pasting from primary:

```
bind-key C-p run "xclip -d `tmux show-env | sed -n s/^DISPLAY=//p` -o | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer"
```

I don't fully understand why `$DISPLAY` isn't correctly set while sourcing  `.tmux.conf`, so this is why I have to extract it with `tmux show-env` and `sed`.

If you have tmux >= 1.8, you can adapt this command with `copy-pipe`:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'xclip -in -selection clipboard -d `tmux show-env | sed -n s/^DISPLAY=//p` >/dev/null'
```

Comment: ``/home/linux/.tmux.conf:11: invalid or unknown command: bind-key C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard -d `tmux show-env | sed -n 's[0/0]
PLAY=//p'` >/dev/null``

Comment: @user the `sed` command you show is not the same as the one I wrote... Is this what you wrote in your `.tmux.conf`?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code.

Comment: @user, strange. There could be many sources of errors. Check first that your quoting is alright. Then, are you familiar with `sed`? The command should be: `sed -n s/^DISPLAY=//p`. Alternatively, you could use `cut`: `tmux show-env DISPLAY | cut -d'=' -f2`. It might also be worth checking your tmux version.

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution on the Arch Wiki using `xclip`:

```
# move tmux copy buffer into x clipboard
bind-key C-y save-buffer /tmp/tmux-buffer \; run-shell "cat /tmp/tmux-buffer | xclip"
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux

Comment: Does tmux create the `save-buffer` file securely in a shared directory? Otherwise putting it in `/tmp` is a security hole. There's a useless use of `cat`, and the removal of the temporary file is missing. Then it's a matter of `xsel` vs `xclip`, which are equivalent here, and you have my (indenpendently written) solution.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I'll update the wiki to reflect your points.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to figure out a decent way to copy what I have in a tmux
>   buffer into my clipboard. I have tried a couple of different things
>   like

For emacs style bindings there are a few different options. (Vi-style should be similar?) The typical binding for doing "copy-selection" in emacs is M-w, so it would be very convenient to have the same binding in tmux.

1 -- Would be ideal, but is non-working (due to tmux limitation?)

```
unbind-key -t emacs-copy M-w
bind-key -t emacs-copy M-w copy-selection\; \
  run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xsel --input --clipboard"
```

2 -- **Compromise that works well for me**: Accept using a different keybinding for emacs-copy in tmux. Use for example C-M-w. (This binding which will be defined "globally" -- not only in copy-mode -- but only useful in copy-mode)

```
bind-key -n C-M-w send-keys M-w\; \
 run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xsel --input --clipboard"
```

Answer (score 3):

Many of these answers didn't work for my Ubuntu 14.04 on zsh as-is. Not sure if my shell had anything to do with it, but here is my working version of using [this strategy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70798/43691) for copy, and [this strategy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36896/43691) for paste.

```
    bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
    bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
    bind-key ] run-shell "xclip -sel clip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

Some notes:

- for copy-pipe, I needed to specify my clipboard with `-sel clip -i`. That line combines the yank to tmux buffer and sends it to xclip.
- to actually paste it, I needed to again specify which clipboard with `-sel clip -o`

This works beautifully now for my vim/zsh/tmux setup.

Comment: thank you! `-sel clip -i` solves the problem. Although, I do not understand why you need to specify clipboard again to paste it (standard `]` works for me)

Answer (score 2):

I use [`copyq`](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) a multiline clipboard manager. (It works with Windows, OSX, Linux.)

- Add the following lines in `~/.tmux.conf`:

  ```
  set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
  bind C-y run 'out=`tmux save-buffer - ` && copyq add "$out"'
  ```
- `cygwin` demands `copyq.exe` location in `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  export PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/CopyQ"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

And improved version of @Leif answer could be:

```
tmux bind-key '[' run "tmux copy-mode;
tmux bind-key -n ']' run \"tmux send-keys Enter; tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard;
tmux unbind-key -n ']'\";
tmux bind-key -n q run \"tmux unbind -n ']'; tmux send-keys q\";
tmux bind-key -n C-c run \"tmux unbind -n ']'; tmux send-keys C-c\""
```

This way there are no consequences if you exit from copy mode in another way besides ], the above code is wrapped in [tundle/tmux-yank](https://github.com/chilicuil/tundle-plugins/tree/master/tmux-yank) a tmux plugin for copying tmux text into the system clipboard, it targets tmux >= 1.6 on OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

On OS-X with tmux version 2.2 or later the following will work:

```
bind-key -t emacs-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
bind-key -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe "pbcopy"
```