# copy (to X clipboard) shortcut in .tmux.conf

Tags: command-line, tmux, clipboard

In order to copy text to X clipboard in tmux, what I currently do is:

- go selection mode with <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>
- start selection with <kbd>space</kbd> (using `mode-keys vi` btw)
- select the text and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
- copy tmux buffer to X clipboard using <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>

(I have a mapping as `bind C-c run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard -i"`

I'm trying to eliminate some of these steps by making a mapping for selection mode. I have tried:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy C-c run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

which gives me and error:

```
.. usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-t key-table] key command [arguments]
```

(I couldn't copy the error)

how can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I have realized I can select and copy to tmux buffer (first 3 steps) using mouse just like a regular selection (although highlighting doesn't last, it still selects the text) and then use the following bind to copy to x clipboard:

```
bind-key -n C-c run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

(I used this method to copy this text and it was easy ;)

note that `-n` denotes "no prefix" therefore no escaping is needed. if you don't get confused by the vanishing highlight this is analogous to regular (common user interface) copying.

this is the best I have come up with so far..

**EDIT2:** turned out <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> overlaps with process interrupt thing so I changed to <kbd>ctrl+alt+c</kbd> for now. (didn't quite like it)

**EDIT3:** tmux 1.8 or so added support to add keybindings in copy mode so now my first original intention is possible using something like:

```
bind-key -tvi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
bind-key -tvi-copy enter copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

These two bindings make it possible to copy text to clipboard when I used <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd> to finish copying.

I still keep this line in case I do the copying with mouse and decide to get the tmux buffer content to clipboard later on:

```
bind-key y run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

Comment: You can change interrupt from ctrl-c to something else using stty.  For example, to use Ctrl-Z: `stty intr=^Z`.  Be careful with that command, it's possible to set a regular character to be the interrupt character (if you do so, use ctrl-v to enter it until fixing the setting).  And don't get confused on what key is used (e.g. ctrl-z is normally the suspend key).

Comment: @ash noted down, thanks.. but I think I will keep `^c` as the interrupt key as I use it more often than copying. I have also updated the answer to reflect my current solution to this problem.

Comment: sounds good.  Also note that many runs of xmodmap can put things in a funny state that is hard to correct, so I recommend starting fresh with a new X session if the affect of commands appears incorrect.

Comment: running `bind-key -t vi-copy C-c run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard -i"` live gives: `Unknown command: run`

Comment: However, running `bind-key C-c run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard -i"` works just fine.

Comment: @gokcehan what are `cat |` in the last version of your commands for? They shouldn't be needed and look odd to me.

Comment: @xaizek I don't know why they were there in the first place but now that I have removed them everything still seems alright, thanks.

Comment: I had an issue with your last proposed solution where tmux wouldn't accept any more keyboard commands after activating that shortcut. This [superuser article](https://superuser.com/questions/653863/tmux-freezes-when-using-ctrl-prefix-ctrl-y/654729#654729) helped me solve it. **tl;dr**: append `&>/dev/null` to the ran command.

Answer (score 19):

This reply doesn't answer directly your question about creating a shortcut. But here's what I do.

You can temporarily suspend passing your keys/mouse events to tmux by holding <kbd>shift</kbd>. So you can press and hold Shift and user regular shortcuts of terminal/X to do the copy. In my case using Terminator, I press <kbd>shift</kbd>, highlight with mouse whatever I want, copy with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd>

And in case you have split panes, you can zoom the current pane with zoom-toggle-key <kbd>Prefix + z</kbd>, and perform the copy operation. (tested on tmux v1.8)

Comment: I wasn't able to use this because of horizontal splits but zooming trick sounds great, thanks for the tip.

Comment: This works in gnome-terminal, for sure; but does it apply to all terminal-emulators? Probably not

Comment: In wsl-terminal, this works. Save my day！

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but have a look at [tmux-yank](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank), as described in [Use system clipboard in vi-copy mode in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131011/use-system-clipboard-in-vi-copy-mode-in-tmux) and [Getting tmux to copy a buffer to the clipboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15715/getting-tmux-to-copy-a-buffer-to-the-clipboard). After installing,

> `prefix + y` - copies text from the command line to clipboard.
>
> #### copy mode bindings:
>
> `y` - copy selection to system clipboard

Comment: I don't have tmux-yank installed, but since a while (maybe 2 month) this kind of shortcut is distracting me very much -> `prefix + c` (while holding ctrl) is inserting the clipboard - and this sometimes comes in my way when I want to create a new window with `prefix + c` (not holding ctrl)  - I wonder why that is