# Use system clipboard in vi-copy mode in tmux

Tags: tmux, xclip

I'm running tmux 1.6 and I'm trying to configure it to use vi-style keybindings as well as use the system clipboard when copying in interactive mode:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' "copy-selection && run \"tmux save-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard\""
```

Simply put, I'd like to be able to do <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and then use <kbd>v</kbd> to begin selecting text for copying, then when <kbd>y</kbd> is pushed, copy the selection to the tmux selection and then export it to the system clipboard using `xclip`.

Unfortunately, when I try to do this, I see the following:

```
.tmux.conf: 14: unknown command: copy-selection && run "tmux save-buffer | xclip -selection clipboard"
```

Is there a way to do this in tmux configuration?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

This was also answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48631/copy-to-x-clipboard-shortcut-in-tmux-conf), but it took me a while to understand how to use it, so I'll explain for anyone else that was confused.

This is basically the setting you're going for:

*(for tmux **versions <2.5**)*

```
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'
```

*(for tmux **versions >=2.5**)*

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'
```

Then hit `Ctrl+b` `[` to enter copy mode. Then hit `Space` followed by whatever vi movement keys to make a selection. Then, instead of hitting `Enter`, hit `y` and the selection will be copied to the clipboard.

Note: this assumes you're using tmux's default bindings with vi keys.

Tmux has different key binding tables for different modes. So, `bind-key -t vi-copy y` sets the action for the `y` key in copy mode. Initially, I was confused because I was used to hitting `Enter` after making a selection. `Enter` is actually just the default key binding for the `copy-selection` command (when in copy mode). The `copy-pipe` command allows us to bind a new key to pipe the selection to a command, which in this case is `xclip`.

You can see all key bindings for copy mode by running `list-keys -t vi-copy`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I had to download and compile tmux 1.9a, but it wasn't so difficult and now it just works™!

Comment: If it doesn't work just double check that `xclip` is actually installed in your system (it's not installed by default on Ubuntu, you need to `sudo apt-get install xclip` to get it)

Comment: For OSX, replace `xclip` with `pbcopy`. For Cygwin on Windows, replace it with `putclip` (from the `cygutils-extra` package).

Comment: The following binding from [this blog entry](https://medium.com/@alexeysamoshkin/tmux-in-practice-integration-with-system-clipboard-bcd72c62ff7b) works great too on Tmux 2.6 and doesn't have the downside of putting seemingly random characters on the screen when copying: `bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"`

Comment: This was not working for me until I removed this line from .tmux.conf: `set -g mouse on`. This is supposed to enable *"mouse mode"* but even after removing it everything regarding my mouse works fine (scroll wheel works, mouse selection works)...

Comment: Just saw SnoringFrog's windows technique now. Prior to knowing that, I got it working for tmux <2.5 in cygwin/windows with:

`bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "cat >/dev/clipboard"`

Comment: Matthias Braun's solution did not work for me initially, but after I made sure to kill all tmux sessions using `tmux ls` and `tmux kill-session -t [id]` it started working. You can enter tmux command mode by doing `prefix + :` and there you can enter the `bind -T copy-mode-vi ... ` command manually to see if it'll work on a fresh session at all

Comment: -bash: bind: -T: invalid option

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned that this `bind` line isn't a terminal command. It belongs in the `~/.tmux.conf` file

Comment: This is all nice and clear, but does not explain how to achieve one the OP's goals: remap in this setup `<Space>` (for starting visual mode/selection) to actual `v` button(to stay consistent with `vim` style). Or is it simply impossible?

Comment: When used over ssh, this solution will copy to remote X clipboard (I presume) rather than the local X clipboard, which would be the intended effect. To copy it to local clipboard, the copy-pipe would have to call a command that relays selection contents over ssh and executes a remote command similar to the one above (`xclip`)

Comment: It is something I would love to be able to do, but sounds like a lot of work for now. I will resort to `cat > ~/.cache/clipboard` as one comment above suggests (but with `/dev/clipboard`)

Comment: For those using 3.3a, and with xclip installed, a simple `set -s copy-command 'xclip -selection clipboard' ` is sufficient. Note this does not bind with Y, you don't need press y after enter. See https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Clipboard#available-tools

Comment: If you additionally to what the config mentioned in this answer provides want to use enter to commit the selection to clipboard, add `unbind enter` before `bind -T copy-mode-vi enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'`

Answer (score 15):

The updated version to [Ben Davis answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131187/228683)

compatible with tmux 2.4

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe "xclip -selection c"
```

Comment: I find it works a bit better with `copy-pipe-and-cancel` rather than `copy-pipe`.  This is on tmux 2.5

Answer (score 11):

I tried a bunch of stuff here and there, but this is what worked form me in my `~/.tmux.conf` file I am using Ubuntu 20 LTS and tmux3.0a

```
#for copying to sys clipboard
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
bind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
bind -T copy-mode-vi C-j send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"

#general other stuff
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
set -g mouse on
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

Comment: wow thanks, found this after 100 obsolete answers. surprised their api has changed so many times

Comment: Nice answer. Catch 22: You need to restart tmux completely (using `tmux kill-server`) after making changes to `~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: Same here...glad to have finally found this. Tried many things, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the tmux-yank plugin for tmux.
https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank

It provides an automated way to copy/paste from tmux to the system clipboard. It works on OSX/Linux/Cygwin systems.

Comment: This works brilliantly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

On Wayland, instead of `xclip`, better use `wl-copy`/`wl-paste` of wl-clipboard package. This works for me:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "wl-copy"
bind C-p run "wl-paste --no-newline | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

**update:** since I use the same [tmux.conf](https://github.com/triebelf/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf) on X11, Wayland, and Cygwin, I ended up with this configuration:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection

if-shell -b 'echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE | grep -q x11' "\
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard > /dev/null'; \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard > /dev/null'; \
    bind-key C-p run 'xclip -out -selection clipboard | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer'"

if-shell -b 'echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE | grep -q wayland' "\
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'wl-copy'; \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'wl-copy'; \
    bind-key C-p run 'wl-paste --no-newline | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer'" "\
    \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'cat - >/dev/clipboard'; \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'cat - >/dev/clipboard'; \
    bind-key C-p run 'cat /dev/clipboard | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer'"
```

Answer (score 5):

You are running into a couple of technical issues:
The “special mode” bindings (e.g. `vi-copy`) …

1. use a different set of commands (i.e. `run-shell` a.k.a. `run` is not available), and
2. do not have the ability to bind multiple commands (which can normally be separated by `;`—the shell’s `&&` command separator is not available).

*tmux* 1.8 has `copy-pipe`, which could help though:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'xclip -selection clipboard >/dev/null'
```

(There is a binding like this listed in [the FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ).)

Comment: I have tmux 1.8 and this doesn't seem to work. (edit) Ugh, I hate textarea inputs that submit on Enter. Anyway, I added this key binding, but when I do <prefix>-y, and hit [space], the contents are not copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Just figured it out. I didn't understand how the "vi-copy" keybinding table worked.

Answer (score 2):

For macOS you can add this line to `.tmux.conf`

`bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'pbcopy'`

Comment: **macOS users, for tmux >= 2.5: `bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'pbcopy'`**

Answer (score 2):

This is what ended up working for me using tmux 2.2 and having installed xclip.
For Vim style copying add the following to .tmux.conf

```
bind Escape copy-mode
bind -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
# Vim style copy to clipboard
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip -selection c > /dev/null"
bind-key p run "xclip -o -sel clip | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

Here when in copy-mode PREFIX v starts the selection and PREFIX y copies to the clipboard. PREFIX p can be used to paste in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

**macOS Big Sur (2021) and Tmux v3.1c:**

I can attest that the below succeeds. That is after trying many of the above unsuccessfully.

```
# Use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi

# Setup 'v' to begin selection as in Vim
unbind -T copy-mode-vi 'v'
unbind -T copy-mode-vi 'y'
unbind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane
unbind -T copy-mode-vi Enter   #this is the default binding for copy (but not to system clipboard)

#(many tried, only this worked)
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'v' send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'y' send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'pbcopy'
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'pbcopy'
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'pbcopy'
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my **X11** clipboard integration (**xsel**), Vim style (copy with y, paste with p)

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xsel -i -p && xsel -o -p | xsel -i -b"            
bind-key p run "xsel -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

with **Wayland** clipboard integration (**wl-clipboard**)

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "wl-copy"                                          
bind-key p run "wl-paste --no-newline | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```