# tmux copy-pipe truncates selection

Tags: tmux

I've noticed tmux copy-pipe truncating selection (leaving out the last part of the selection).

Eg:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip -in -sel clipboard"
```

Sometimes only copies the first few 100 bytes into the buffer.

I don't think this is an issue with `xclip` since this happens with `xsel` too.

For some reason piping into a file, sleeping, then passing to xclip works.

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y \
  send-keys -X copy-pipe "cat > /tmp/tmux_clip.txt" \; \
  run "sleep 0.1" \; \
  run -b "xclip -in -sel clipboard /tmp/tmux_clip.txt > /dev/null" \; \
  display "Clipboard Copy"
```

Is this a known issue? are there ways to resolve this?

Comment: This seems to be a new occurrence, as it used to work just fine. Happening now for me too though. You can sort of work around it with `tmux show-buffer | xsel -ib`, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `set-clipboard` option set to `on` or `external` (default) and your terminal support OSC 52 then `copy-pipe` will also send the copied data to your tty using an xterm escape sequence to set the selection. tmux correctly sends the whole copied text, but your terminal may have a limited-size buffer to receive the data. This is mentioned on [tmux#1119](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1119).

It may work sometimes because the call to `xclip` is put in the background and may finish after the built-in clipboard setting operation. Additionally, this may have started happening recently if you updated your terminal and it implemented OSC 52 support (e.g. [alacritty](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty/issues/1002)).

Your options are:

- Add `set-option -g set-clipboard off` to your tmux config
- set a higher buffer size limit in your terminal if possible (or file an issue) and ditch `copy-pipe` entirely

keywords: tmux clipboard truncated, tmux doesn't copy all characters, tmux copy truncated

Answer (score 0):

I have started seeing the same issue, but don't have a good explanation for why. However, the proposed tmux >= 2.5 solution over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131187/44909 fixes the issue for me. Specifically, make your `.tmux.conf` have:

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'
```

The `-and-cancel` bit seems to be what does it. If I just use `copy-pipe` it does not work.