# TMUX 2.3 copy to clipboard

Tags: tmux, clipboard, xclip

I am using TMUX 2.3 just recently copying stopped working.

Here is the relevant section that lets me copy stuff to the clipboard:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
```

I made sure `xclip` is installed.

One thing I found out is this git commit in the tmux repository: [Fundamental change to how copy mode key bindings work (76d6d3)](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/76d6d3641f271be1756e41494960d96714e7ee58)

So I know that the keybindings changed but I cannot make out how to rewrite those two lines so they are working.

I am aware of the following questions though I believe they do not solve the problem I have.

- [copy (to X clipboard) shortcut in .tmux.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48631/copy-to-x-clipboard-shortcut-in-tmux-conf)
- [Use system clipboard in vi-copy mode in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131011/use-system-clipboard-in-vi-copy-mode-in-tmux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also stumbled upon this issue. After some googling I found the solution on a japanese blog [here](http://nyangryy.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/10/18/180944).

Instead of doing `bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"`
Do something like this:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
```