# Copy / paste text selections between tmux and the clipboard

Tags: terminal, tmux, clipboard

I am running the latest version of tmux (from the git repository) and xclip (0.12), and I would like to be able to use Emacs-like keyboard bindings to move around the text in `copy-mode`, copy (`M-w`) selections to the clipboard, and paste (`C-y`) from/to the copy buffer to the clipboard.

So far I have been able to paste text with `C-y`, and move around in `copy-mode` with Emacs-like keyboard bindings, but **I am still unable to copy text** from a tmux buffer (e.g. in `copy-mode`)

I found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15715/getting-tmux-to-copy-a-buffer-to-the-clipboard) for copying the entire buffer to the clipboard (and viceversa), but it does not seem to be working for me.

Also, in the `tmux-users` mail list  I was told that recent versions of tmux (only in the git repo) provide a command called `copy-pipe`. The man page says the following about this command:

> One command in accepts an argument, copy-pipe, which copies the
>   selection and pipes it to a command.  For example the following will
>   bind ‘C-q’ to copy the selection into /tmp as well as the paste
>   buffer:
>
> ```
>        bind-key -temacs-copy C-q copy-pipe "cat >/tmp/out"
> ```

It looks like `copy-pipe` is meant to be used in part to pipe the selection to another command. There also seem to be some typos in this description and in the command (what is `temacs-copy`?)

Either way, what I would like to do is:

#### Copying:

1. Enter copy mode
2. Move to the text I want to copy using Emacs navigation commands (i.e. `C-f`,`C-b`, `M-f`, `M-b`, `C-a`, `C-e` etc. to move the cursor). **No prefix** for any of these.
3. Copy the selected text into the clipboard with: `M-w` (**no prefix** either)

#### Pasting:

1. I would like to be able to type `C-y` (**without** having to enter `copy-mode`) to paste text in the terminal (**no prefix** either)

I have tried the following for copying without luck:

```
bind-key -n M-w run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

However, pasting works great:

```
bind-key -n C-y run "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

The odd thing is that I know that the "`xclip -i -selection clipboard`" part of the copy command above works well, since **I can** copy things to the clipboard in the command line, e.g.:

```
echo "Hello world. How are you?" | xclip -i -selection clipboard
```

With all this, **how can I copy a selection from copy mode to the clipboard?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the following  `tmux.conf` with `copy-pipe` in the new versions of tmux (1.8+):

```
set -g mouse on
# To copy:
bind-key -n -t emacs-copy M-w copy-pipe "xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c "

# To paste:
bind-key -n C-y run "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"
```

1. `prefix+[` into copy-mode
2. select content with mouse(hold)
3. `M-w` to copy that part into system clipboard
4. `C-y` the paste it inside tmux, `C-v` to paste it inside other regular application like web browser.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes, it's the best for Linux-based setups.

Comment: In tmux 2.0 it's `run-shell` instead of `run`

Comment: @LouisKottmann : why just Linux-based?

Comment: I cannot comment on other systems, but I believe mac uses bpaste instead of xclip usually

Comment: In tmux 2.8 I had to change them into 
```bind -Tcopy-mode M-w send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c "``` . 
```bind-key -n C-y run-shell "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - ; tmux paste-buffer"``` 
according to [this commit](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/76d6d3641f271be1756e41494960d96714e7ee58) suggested by [starfry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363191/141936)

Answer (score 10):

Please note that, with Tmux 2.4 (since [this commit](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/76d6d3641f271be1756e41494960d96714e7ee58)), the binding syntax has changed. I paraphrase [this Github comment](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/754#issuecomment-297452143) to summarise the change briefly:

1. replace `-t` with `-T`
2. replace `vi-<name>` with `<name>-mode-vi`
3. prefix the command with `send-keys -X`

I had:

```
bind-key -n -t vi-copy Enter copy-pipe 'xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c'
bind-key -n -t vi-copy MouseDragEnd1Pane copy-pipe 'xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c'
```

which I needed to change to:

```
bind-key -n -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe 'xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c'
bind-key -n -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe 'xclip -i -sel p -f | xclip -i -sel c'
```

---

From the [changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES):

> Key tables have undergone major changes. Mode key tables are no longer
>     separate from the main key tables. All mode key tables have been removed,
>     together with the -t flag to bind-key and unbind-key.
>
> The emacs-edit, vi-edit, emacs-choose and vi-choose tables have been replaced
>     by fixed key bindings in the command prompt and choose modes. The mode-keys
>     and status-keys options remain.
>
> The emacs-copy and vi-copy tables have been replaced by the copy-mode and
>     copy-mode-vi tables. Commands are sent using the -X and -N flags to
>     send-keys. So the following:

```
bind -temacs-copy C-Up scroll-up
bind -temacs-copy -R5 WheelUpPane scroll-up
```

> Becomes:

```
bind -Tcopy-mode C-Up send -X scroll-up
bind -Tcopy-mode WheelUpPane send -N5 -X scroll-up
```

> These changes allows the full command parser (including command sequences) and
>     command set to be used - for example, the normal command prompt with editing
>     and history is now used for searching, jumping, and so on instead of a custom
>     one. The default C-r binding is now:

```
bind -Tcopy-mode C-r command-prompt -p'search up' "send -X search-backward-incremental '%%'"
```

> There are also some new commmands available with send -X, such as
>     copy-pipe-and-cancel.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure out why this didn't work for me, until I realized xclip didn't exist on my machine. Apparently it's not always installed by default. Hopefully this will save someone some time.

Answer (score 8):

While other answers may help, here's how I do the same:

- Shift + select the text with the cursor.
- Ctrl + Shift + C to copy the text to clipboard.

Comment: This is a fair answer but the problems begin when you have two or more panes arranged horizontally.

Comment: I see, let me know if you find something useful for that.

Comment: `prefix` + `z` zooms in on the selected pane so that horizontal splits are not an issue when bypassing tmux copy selection by holding `shift`.

Comment: This is the simplest and most consistent solution I've found to copy and paste between tmux and firefox. I've been searching for something like this for 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

The `-temacs-copy` is not a typo. The leading dash means that this is an option to the `bind-keys` command (along with an argument for the option). It is equivalent to `-t emacs-copy`, if you like that better.

Copy mode uses a different set of bindings and commands<sup>1</sup> than the “normal mode”. The `copy-pipe` command is only available in the alternate “mode” bindings tables. When `mode-keys` is `emacs`, copy mode will use the `emacs-copy` table, so you need to bind M-w to `copy-pipe` in the that table.

```
bind-key -temacs-copy M-w copy-pipe "xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

---

Be careful making too many “no prefix” bindings. They will make it difficult to type those bound keys to a program running inside *tmux* (e.g. when you want to type C-y to a tty-mode instance of *Emacs* running inside *tmux*). You can always (prefix) bind some key that does `send-keys C-y`, but that might make it more cumbersome to type if you need it often enough.

---

<sup>1</sup> Only movement and editing commands are available. With the exception of `copy-pipe`, these commands do not take any arguments (this is what the man page means with it says “One command in accepts an argument”; the “in” is probably a typo or an editing mistake).