# Running shell commands from inside tmux is causing Gnome terminal to break <prefix> key

Tags: tmux, gnome-terminal

I am running tmux inside gnome terminal and have been trying to use a binding to copy the contents of tmux's paste buffer to my Linux X clipboard. A lot of places on the internet recommend this:

```
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard"
```

This command works perfectly from the command line:

```
tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard
```

If I bind the shell command to a key and use it from inside tmux (using `bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard"`), it does copy the tmux save-buffer to my clipboard; once I have copied some text in tmux's "copy" mode, using this binding will load the text into my X clipboard, ready to be pasted into a browser or anywhere else.
However, it *_also_*  causes the prefix key to stop working for that terminal.
If I kill the terminal with tmux running inside it and open another terminal and re-attach to tmux, the prefix key will continue working in another terminal.
I also tried the following approach:

Set up an executable file: `/usr/local/bin/tmux_to_clip` with the command in it

```
% cat /usr/local/bin/tmux_to_clip 
#!/bin/bash

tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard
```

and then call the command from inside tmux

```
:run tmux_to_clip
```

again, it successfully copies the command to the clipboard, but again it breaks the prefix key. How can I prevent this and get a keybinding for copying tmux `save-buffer` to the X clipboard?

Comment: I believe this is caused by the way in which `xclip` forks, although that is just a hunch for trying out as many combinations of `run-shell` that I can (with pipes, without pipes, using other programs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same (annoying) problem.
It seems that using `xsel -ib` instead of `xclip -i -sel clipboard`, as suggested [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77587), works!

So the final binding should be:

`bind C-y run "tmux save-buffer - | xsel -ib"`