# Tmux run-shell xclip not working

Tags: shell, tmux, debugging, clipboard, xclip

I am using tmux 2.3 and want to define a command to send the paste-buffer to system clipboard. I have tried using the command below and every variant I can think of, but when I try to run it, I get a message saying it returns with exit code 1. When the run the command in sh it works fine and when I remove the xclip part it doesn't throw an error. How can I debug what is causing the error? I believe I have the correct command.

```
bind-key b run-shell "tmux show-buffer | xclip -sel clip -i > /dev/null"
```

Answer (score -1):

> *note: the original question referred to `tmux` version 2.3, and I confirmed
> all of this works with both that version, and 3.2a*

For me, this has usually been caused by the `tmux` session starting without the
`DISPLAY` environment variable set, meaning `xclip` doesn't know how to
communicate with the X Server. [This AskUbuntu answer is more focused on SSH,
but it includes a helpful paragraph](https://askubuntu.com/a/305681):

> To check whether X11 forwarding is enabled, look at the value of the DISPLAY
> environment variable: `echo $DISPLAY`. You should see a value like
> `localhost:10` [...]. Note that if `DISPLAY` isn't set, it's no use setting
> it manually [...]

This is what it looks like in my local, non-SSH `tmux` session:

```shellsession
$ echo "${DISPLAY:?}"
:0
```

If you get something like the following, it means the `DISPLAY` variable isn't set:

```shellsession
$ echo "${DISPLAY:?}"
sh: 1: DISPLAY: parameter null or not set
```

It's better to figure out how to launch the `tmux` session inside the X Server
session, but if you can launch a terminal inside the X Server session, it could
be useful to find out what the `DISPLAY` variable is, and temporarily set it in
the `tmux` session, to see if it works:

```sh
export DISPLAY=':0'
```

[The Ubuntu Community Wiki has a brief and exhaustive introduction to shell
variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) (it mentions `bash`, but most of the info is
applicable to most shells, except `csh`, `tcsh`, and `fish`, which are not
POSIX_compliant); it describes `DISPLAY` near the end. Note that the `export VARIABLE_NAME=value` syntax is part of the POSIX shell programming language,
and is very counter intuitive, even for those with experience in other
languages. [This Stack Exchange question has some more explanations of how to
set environment variables.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16303/235043)

You can usually start any command-line program inside an X Server session by
starting a terminal application, and then running the command-line program
using the shell in the terminal.

On GNOME this would look like:

1. Login to your account
2. [Start Terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome_help/stable/shell_apps_open.html.en)
3. Run `tmux new-session` as a command in Terminal (sometimes it connects to
   an already-running session anyways)

Once started, `tmux` will launch a shell with the `DISPLAY` environment
variable set, and `xclip` should work:

```shellsession
$ xclip -verbose -out
Connecting to X server.
Using UTF8_STRING.
```

You may see other things, and if your clipboard already contains content, it
will be echoed to the terminal. Try copying, highlighting, or selecting some
text before running this.

If instead it shows:

```shellsession
xclip: command not found
```

This means that `xclip` isn't installed, or can't be found.

If `xclip` is working, then you can try to set the command as a `tmux` key
binding (running this will probably only work when already inside a `tmux`
session):

```sh
tmux bind-key -T prefix b run-shell "tmux show-buffer | xclip -se c -i > /dev/null"
```

> *running `tmux list-keys | less` shows the default key bindings, and the
> syntax for setting them in a configuration file*

I explicitly added the keybinding to the `prefix` table. Commands (or keyboard
shortcuts) in `tmux`'s `prefix` table are run by first pressing a leading key
sequence, which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> by default, or C-b in `tmux`'s
syntax.  Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> then <kbd>b</kbd> (C-b b) should
run the command.  I'll use <kbd>prefix</kbd> to indicate that the prefix key
combination should be pressed.

And we do get an error. `tmux` opens copy-mode with the content `'tmux show-buffer | xclip -se c -i > /dev/null' returned 1`.

If the command run by `run-shell` prints any output to stdout, `tmux` opens
copy-mode in the current pane, showing that output. If the shell command fails,
it also displays a line stating the return or exit code. By default,
<kbd>prefix</kbd> then <kbd>q</kbd> will exit copy-mode.

Many programs print errors to stderr instead of stdout, including `tmux`'s
`show-buffer`, so the error information is lost. To capture it, we can leave
off the shell pipe, and change the shell redirection:

```shellsession
$ tmux show-buffer
no buffers

$ echo $?  # prints 1 if the previous command failed
1

$ tmux run-shell "tmux show-buffer"
'tmux show-buffer' returned 1

$ tmux run-shell "tmux show-buffer 2>&1"
no buffers
'tmux show-buffer 2>&1' returned 1
```

This error message is returned because, when `tmux` starts, by default there
are no buffers.

If there are any buffers, the following command will show those buffers and
their contents (by default, it's bound to <kbd>prefix</kbd> then <kbd>=</kbd>):

```sh
tmux choose-buffer
```

If there are no buffers, this command returns immediately with no output. If
there are any buffers, `choose-buffer` presents a list containing all buffers,
ordered by the last time they were used. Pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> and
<kbd>↓</kbd> will scroll through the list, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will
paste the contents of the selected buffer to the current pane, and <kbd>q</kbd>
will exit.

To create a buffer, used the `set-buffer` command:

```sh
$ tmux set-buffer "test content"
$ tmux save-buffer - && echo
test content
```

> *note: the `&& echo` is needed because the content of the buffer does not end
> in a new-line*

With at least one buffer, the `show-buffer` command opens copy-mode with the
contents of the most recently set buffer.

Note as in the above shell session that the `save-buffer` command will print
the contents of the most recently set buffer to a file, and if `-` is given as
the filename, then it will print to stdout.

The original configuration should probably be*****:

```text
bind-key b run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -sel clip -i"
```

*****I'm guessing that you're trying to copy something from `tmux` to the
system clipboard.

Typically, text in `tmux` is selected by entering copy-mode first. By default,
this is bound to <kbd>prefix</kbd> then <kbd>[</kbd>. With the default
configuration, `tmux` uses Emacs-style keybindings in copy-mode. In `tmux`
version 2.3, these keybindings can be shown with `tmux list-keys -temacs-copy`.
In versions greater than 2.3, the `list-keys` command shows the keybindings in
all tables by default.

> *note: `vi`-style keybindings can be used by replacing `emacs-copy` with
> `vi-copy`, or `copy-mode-vi` instead of `copy-mode`, in all commands and
> configurations*

The selected text can be copied, both to the system clipboard and a `tmux`
buffer. In `tmux` version 2.3, this is possible with something like:

```text
bind-key -temacs-copy M-w copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard -in"
```

This would override the default behaviour of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> in
copy-mode to pipe the selected text to `xclip`, in addition to copying the
selected text into a `tmux` buffer.

In versions greater than 2.3, the equivalent configuration would be:

```text
bind-key -T copy-mode M-w send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection clipboard -in"
```

In both versions, the following would replace the default behaviour of
<kbd>prefix</kbd> then <kbd>]</kbd> with creating a `tmux` buffer with the
contents of the X server clipboard, and then pasting the most recent buffer:

```text
bind-key -T prefix ']' run-shell 'tmux set-buffer "$(xclip -selection clipboard -out)"' \; paste-buffer
```

Note that [`xclip` can behave strangely in some circumstances when used like this.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77587)

[Version 2.3 was released in 2016,](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases/tag/2.3) so most package repositories should
have a newer version.

Either way, I would recommend using [`tmux-yank`](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-yank), as it manages the task of
copying from `tmux` very well.

---

As to debugging what is causing errors in `tmux` configurations, in general,
there are a few things we can do to make that easier:

- Run the commands from the terminal inside a `tmux` session (if possible)
- Create a temporary configuration file
- Show messages for longer

### Run the commands from the terminal inside a `tmux` session (if possible)

Most commands that can be put in a configuration file, can also be run from
inside a `tmux` session, from a command line, by prefixing them with `tmux`.
Most shells will interpret certain characters like `[` `]` `;` `&` `"` `'`
specially, so when running `tmux` commands, take care to quote those characters
so that they are passed to `tmux`. All of the commands given above will work
when prefixed with `tmux`, without modification, as well as in a configuration
file.

Running the commands like this may not be possible, like when in copy-mode and
the shell session isn't available.

When it is possible, this can help diagnose what exactly is happening with each
part of a command.

Sometimes, the command can be run from `tmux`'s command prompt (by default
<kbd>prefix</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd>). The command is entered just as in the
configuration file, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> runs it.

So for instance, in copy-mode, pressing <kbd>prefix</kbd> then <kbd>:</kbd>
changes the status line to yellow with the content `:`, followed by the cursor.
Typing a command like `display-message test` and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>
will set the content of the status line to `test`. To instead exit, press the
terminal's interrupt key combination (default in most terminals is
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>; `stty -a` may show something like `intr = ^C`).

> *note: see the section "Show messages for longer" to increase how long these
> messages are shown in the status line*

> *note: `tmux` version 2.4 and above allow running copy-mode commands from the
> command prompt, like `send-keys -X begin-selection`. I do not know how to do
> this in version earlier than 2.4.*

### Create a temporary configuration file

To help with debugging, we can add the potential configuration changes in a
file called `tmux_debug.conf`:

```text
# -q: do not return an error if the file doesn't exist
source-file -q /etc/tmux.conf
source-file -q ~/.tmux.conf

# add any experimental configuration below here
```

and run `tmux` with:

```sh
tmux -f ./tmux_debug.conf
```

When `tmux` is started, by default it reads from two configuration files:
`/etc/tmux.conf` and `~/.tmux.conf`. The `-f` option instructs it to ignore
those, and load a custom file. Since we may rely on configuration in those two,
we source them if they exist. This will allow us to keep our current
configuration without making permanent changes to it.

We can also add a keybinding for quick reloading of the temporary configuration
file:

```text
bind-key -T prefix C-r source-file ./tmux_debug.conf \; display-message "sourced configuration"
```

This will set the key sequence <kbd>prefix</kbd> then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to make `tmux` reload the `tmux_debug.conf` file
in the directory in which `tmux` was started, and then show the text `sourced configuration` in `tmux`'s status line.

### [Show messages for longer](https://superuser.com/a/295744)

The previous command displays a message in the status line. By default, `tmux`
only shows messages in the status line for 750ms, which is a source of
frustration.

In the configuration file, adding the following line will cause the text to be
displayed until a key is pressed:

```text
set -g display-time 0
```

> *note: the key press is sent to whatever is running in the pane or window
> that just had focus*