# Where can I find all tmux options?

Tags: tmux

Where can I find a list of all tmux options? I know of `tmux list-keys -t <table>` which shows you various keybindings and their commands, but I'm looking for a comprehensive list of all possible tmux commands.

Comment: Are you looking for *options* or *commands*?

Answer (score 8):

I have memorized `tmux list-keys | less` and `tmux show -gw | less` (I also check just `-g`, `-w`, and `-s` when I think I'm missing something).

That usually gives me anything I need to know, or set. I use `man tmux` then `/OPTIONS` for more.

Also remember that any command you would issue to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> can also be passed to the `tmux` cli/cmd though tab-completion is a trick to set up there.

Answer (score 1):

Running `man tmux` in the terminal displays the manual which has all available options.
There are also online versions of the manual (e.g. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/tmux.1.html)

Comment: The following online man page has been linked from the official page: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1

Comment: That doesn't seem to include everything. For example begin-selection can't be found in the manpages.

Comment: @phk Thanks- I didn't go to the official tmux page, I just googled.
I ran diff between the Ubuntu man and the OpenBSD man and can't see any differences

Comment: @dani-h I've been looking for references to begin-selection and have only found 2 apart from the source code (http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36896/109534) and (https://gist.github.com/snuggs/800936), so the source code is probably the way to go.

Comment: `man` does not work if `tmux` was installed through `conda`.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no formal documentation I found some of it in the source code.
https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux/blob/master/mode-key.c for mode mappings

Answer (score 1):

To list the options you can use

```
tmux show -A
```

(`show` is an alias for the longer `show-options`).

The `-A` option will show all the options in effect (with inherited options marked with an asterisk). You can also use `-g` (to show the global options), `-p` (for pane options), `-w` (window options) or `-s` (for session options).

Answer (score 0):

options-table.c at source

> - This file has a tables with all the server, session and window  * options. These tables are the master copy of the options with their
>     real  * (user-visible) types, range limits and default values.

Answer (score 0):

Extract them from manpage

```
function tmux__list_options {
  local range
  case $1 in
    -s)
      range='/^ {5}Available server options/,/^ {5}Available session options/p'
      ;;
    -e)
      range='/^ {5}Available session options/,/^ {5}Available window options/p'
      ;;
    -w)
      range='/^ {5}Available window options/,/^ {5}Available pane options/p'
      ;;
    -p)
      range='/^ {5}Available pane options/,/^[A-Z]/p'
      ;;
    *)
      range='/^ {5}Available server options/,/^[A-Z]/p'
      ;;
  esac
  man -P cat tmux | sed -En "$range" | grep -E --color=never '^ {5}[a-z]'
}
```